# in Google maps javascript click function is not working

Tags: jquery, google-maps

My very first question in here. I am building a google maps by getting the data from json object given from external php file, in there It gets me the list of restaurants (in this case 4 restaurants) and their info, and with this info I build the markers on the map and then show the list of restaurants, and when I click the name of restaurant it should show it in the map, from the marker, and this function is not working, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"proxy.php",
       dataType:"json",
       contentType:"text/json",
       success:function(res){
           $.post('getinfo.php', {data: res}, function(data){

                response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  
                if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("google_map_div"));
                    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
                    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
                    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0,0),0);

                    var side_bar_html = "";
                    var gmarkers = [];
                    var htmls = [];
                    var i = 0;

                    function createMarker(point,name,html) {
                        var marker = new GMarker(point);
                        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
                        });
                        gmarkers[i] = marker;
                        htmls[i] = html;
                        side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:openInsideMap(' + i + ')">' + name + '</a><br>';
                        return marker;
                        //
                     }

                     function openInsideMap(i){
                        alert("WORKING" + i);
                        gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
                     }

                    var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();

                    for(i=0; i<response.length;i++){
                        var j = i + 1;
                        // obtain the attribues of each marker
                        var lat = parseFloat(response[i].langt);
                        var lng = parseFloat(response[i].longt);
                        var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                        var html = response[i].localName + ": " + response[i].localAddress;
                        if(response[i].tapaName == ''){
                            var label = j + ". " + response[i].localName + " - " + response[i].localAddress;
                        }else{
                            var label = j + ". " + response[i].localName + " - " + response[i].localAddress + "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + response[i].tapaName;
                        }
                        // create the marker
                        var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
                        map.addOverlay(marker);

                        // ==== Each time a point is found, extent the bounds ato include it =====
                        bounds.extend(point);

                    }

                    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
                    map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
                    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
                }

           });
       }
   });
```

WHEN I BROWSE IT IN MOZILLA OR GCHROME, IT SAYS THAT function openInsideMap(i){ IS NOT DEFINED
openInsideMap is not defined

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP,
AND THE LINK TO CHECK IT IS:
http://www.gsi.dec.usc.es/santiagoetapas/testStage.php

Answer (score 0):

`openInsideMap` is only defined in the anonymous function that starts:

```
function(data){
                response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

You can fix this by using an event listener instead of a javascript URL.  E.g., assuming `document.getElementById("side_bar")` initially has no children:

```
function createMarker(point,name,html) {
                        var marker = new GMarker(point);
                        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
                        });
                        gmarkers[i] = marker;
                        htmls[i] = html;
                        var newLink = document.createElement("a");
                        newLink.addEventListener("click", 
                       (function(i)
                       {
                         return function()
                         {
                           openInsideMap(i);
                         };
                       })(i), false);
                       document.getElementById("side_bar").appendChild(newLink);
                        return marker;
                        //
                     }
```

Now `openInsideMap` will be closed in.  The anonymous function is necessary so you don't always get the latest `i`.

And then remove:

```
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
```

Comment: in fact this is the data that I am working with for the google maps:
which function(data).
I tried to put the function openInsideMap(i) outside the ajax function, but it still says function undefined.
And as well, I need the 'i' for knowing which restaurant I am pushing in order to pass it to the map marker

Comment: now the side bar is gone, it doesnt show anything, where as I put
newLink.innerText = name;
after
var newLink = document.createElement("a");

Comment: Is there any way of having the .ajax  AND the $.post, because I put the lat, logt myself, not from json file, it is working, but if i put for example only $(document).ready() around them, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Matthew,
I tried what you have told me, but it didn't work, so I read a little about global and local variables in javascript, then I solved the problem by, first of all , taking out:

- $(document).ready

And then, I put the function openInsideMap(i); outside the ajax, and as well put the variables used in this function outside the ajax

- var gmarkers = [];
- var htmls = [];

And it is working great. You can check by link: [www.gsi.dec.usc.es/santiagoetapas/testStage.php](http://www.gsi.dec.usc.es/santiagoetapas/testStage.php)